# How do I override plugin templates and stylesheets?

Tags: plugins, templates

Can I easily override plugin's templates and stylesheets in my child theme or does the plugin have to provide functionalities to do this?

I have overridden template files for some of the plugins in the past but some of them don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

So long as a plugin / theme doesn't use the dreaded !important rule in their CSS files, you should be quite alright to include your own CSS, and over-ride their settings. However some very badly written plugins / themes do use the !important rule, which unfortunately makes it difficult or even impossible to over-ride their styling.

In situations like this, it's best to find what priority level and name they register their style sheet under, and unhook it via wp_dequeue_style( $handle );. It works the same as registering a stylesheet. In situations that require this, what I do is just de-queue their style sheet, copy it completely, and then make the changes I need accordingly. This is the most upgrade-friendly method of doing it, as it does not require you to modify their files directly.

Comment: Any reason for a downvote?

Comment: Do you know how to override the php template of a plugin? I also need to do this along with the CSS.

Comment: Unless the plugin specifically uses the locate_template function, or otherwise uses a filter or an action hook, then no. In that case, modifying the plugins files directly would be your only option.

However, if the plugin uses a built in wordpress function that has a hook built into it, you can tap in that way. A good example would be a plugin that uses the_content(). You can add a content filter to modify it's output that way.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which uses `wp_enqueue_style()` to enqueue your stylesheet. Then hook your function to `wp_enqueue_scripts` using `add_action()`, making sure to use a priority (third argument) that is higher than the priority used by the plugin to enqueue its stylesheet.

Refs:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts

Comment: I also need to override the entire template php file, not just the stylesheet. I want to be able to add my own markup. Is there a way to do this?